# Trying to divide two columns of a dataframe but get Nan

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**Background**:

I deal with a dataframe and want to divide the two columns of this dataframe to get a new column. The code is shown below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'drive_mile': [15.1, 2.1, 7.12], 'price': [40, 9, 31]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['price/km'] = df[['drive_mile', 'price']].apply(lambda x: x[1]/x[0])
print(df)
```

And I get the below result:

```
drive_mile  price  price/km
0       15.10     40       NaN
1        2.10      9       NaN
2        7.12     31       NaN
```

Why would this happen? And how can I fix it?

Comment: `df[['drive_mile', 'price']].apply(lambda x: x[1]/x[0], axis = 1)`

Comment: Thx, never thought it could be so easy...

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using apply? a more efficient way would be ``df.price/df.drive_mile``

Comment: I'm used to using apply to process a dataframe, so I didn't think too much about that. I'll use division directly next time, thx!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you missed the `axis=1` parameter to perform the division on the right dimension using apply. This is because you end up with different indices when joining back in the DataFrame.

However, more importantly, **do not use apply to perform a division!**. Apply is often much less efficient compared to vectorial operations.

Use `div`:

```
df['price/km'] = df['drive_mile'].div(df['price'])
```

Or `/`:

```
df['price/km'] = df['drive_mile']/df['price']
```

Comment: Okay, I think it is a safer and faster way to do it, thx!

Comment: After applying this method, still getting a few row values as NaN. Any help?